# efficient way to iterate through coo_matrix elements ordered by column?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` matrix which I want to convert to bitsets per column for further calculation. (for the purpose of the example, I'm testing on 100Kx1M).

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
bitsets = [ intbitset() for _ in range(matrix.shape[1]) ]
for i,j in itertools.izip(matrix.row, matrix.col):
  bitsets[j].add(i)
```

That works, but COO matrix iterates the values by row. Ideally, I'd like to iterate by columns and then just build the bitset at once instead of adding to a different bitset every time.

Couldn't find a way to iterate the matrix column-based. Is there?

I don't mind converting to other sparse formats, but couldn't find a way to efficiently iterate the matrix there. (using `nonzero()` on CSC matrix has been proven to be extremely not efficient...)

Thanks!

Comment: `nonzero` on sparse matrix just returns the `coo` row/col, regardless of the format.  Check its code.  In general the elements in `coo` format are unordered.  Conversion to/from `csr` or `csc` might order them by row or col.

Comment: thanks!. m.tocsc().tocoo() and then iterating over row/col gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Make a small sparse matrix:

```
In [82]: M = sparse.random(5,5,.2, 'coo')*2
In [83]: M
Out[83]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [84]: print(M)
  (1, 3)    0.03079661961875302
  (0, 2)    0.722023291734881
  (0, 3)    0.547594065264775
  (1, 0)    1.1021150713641839
  (1, 2)    0.585848976928308
```

That `print`, as well as the `nonzero` return the `row` and `col` arrays:

```
In [85]: M.nonzero()
Out[85]: (array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([3, 2, 3, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Conversion to `csr` orders the rows (but not necessarily the columns).  `nonzero` converts back to `coo` and returns the row and col, with the new order.

```
In [86]: M.tocsr().nonzero()
Out[86]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 0, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

I was going to say conversion to `csc` orders the columns, but it doesn't look like that:

```
In [87]: M.tocsc().nonzero()
Out[87]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 0, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

Transpose of csr produces a csc:

```
In [88]: M.tocsr().T.nonzero()
Out[88]: (array([0, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32), array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int32))
```

I don't fully follow what you are trying to do, or why you want a column sort, but the `lil` format might help:

```
In [90]: M.tolil().rows
Out[90]: 
array([list([2, 3]), list([0, 2, 3]), list([]), list([]), list([])],
      dtype=object)
In [91]: M.tolil().T.rows
Out[91]: 
array([list([1]), list([]), list([0, 1]), list([0, 1]), list([])],
      dtype=object)
```

In general iteration on sparse matrices is slow.  Matrix multiplication in the `csr` and `csc` formats is the fastest operation.  And many other operations make use of that indirectly (e.g. row sum).  Another relatively fast set of operations are ones that can work directly with the `data` attribute, without paying attention to row or column values.

`coo` doesn't implement indexing or iteration.  `csr` and `lil` implement those.