# Appy function on sparse martix according to its col value

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to apply a function on a sparse martix according to the column value.The wanted matrix is new_mtx. This code does exactly what I want but this takes too much time (I'm doing NLP so I have a huge database).

Because an example is always easier to understand :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

row = np.array([0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1 ,2,2,2,2,2 ,3,3,3,3,3 ,4,4,4,4,4 ])
col = np.array([0,1,2,3,4, 0,1,2,3,4, 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4 ])
data = np.arange(1,26)
mtx = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(5, 5))

coef = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3,4:4}

new_mtx = mtx.copy()
for i in range(0,mtx.shape[0]):
     for j in range (0,mtx.shape[1]):
        new_mtx[i,j] = pow(coef[i],mtx[i,j])
```

Is there a faster way to achieve this with build-in function ?

Comment: Does `coef` have to be a dictionary?  Why not just a list, or even array?  Indexing individual elements of sparse matrix like this, regardless of whether they are 0 or not is about the slowest thing you can do.  If `mtx` really is sparse, it has a lot of 0s.  `pow` with 0 is 1, so `new_mtx` will not be sparse.  Try demonstrating this with a matrix like `mtx = (sparse.random(5,5,.4,'csr')*5).astype(int)`.  And show the desired results.

Comment: I know, I've found build-in function for the rest of the code but I can't seem to find one that does that, that's why I'm asking it. THis is only yo show what is supposed to be achieved.
The next step is multiplying every element of a line and if the value was zero previously in mtx then it's supposed to ignore it (so making it a 1 seem a good idea to me but there might be a more efficient way to do so)

Comment: If `new_mtx` is going to be dense anyways, you might as well make `mtx` dense as well.   Sparse matrix is best for operations like matrix multiplication.  Look at my answer to this current SO question [efficient way to iterate through coo_matrix elements ordered by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936510)